# Perpendicular falloff material

Tags: three.js

I want to make a falloff semi-transparent shader, opaque when normals are perpendicular to camera direction and transparent when normals face towards the camera. Here is the code I use so far :

```
vec3 vertexNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
vec3 viewDir = vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
float dotProd = dot(vertexNormal, viewDir);
alpha = abs ( 1.0 - dotProd );
```

It works but when the objects are not located in the center of the camera view, the falloff isn't consistent anymore, farther side have a larger falloff :

Falloff larger towards edge of camera view
[image: Falloff larger towards edge of camera view]

Is there a way to get consistent falloff thickness all over the camera view (all sphere would be distorded by perspective but the falloff contour would be the same everywhere) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a really high field of view?

Comment: Is this orthographic or perspective actually?

Comment: Try `viewDir = normalize( - modelViewPosition );` You will have to calculate the model view position.

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you! It worked, I had to mix both answers,
`viewDir = normalize( -modelViewPosition.xyz );` worked fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you’re using an orthographic camera your view dir is incorrect.

Try

```
vec4 vp = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.);
vec3 viewdir = - normalize(vp.xyz);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to add normalize() and it works as expected.